# Can I do an SVN update on multiple projects and skip failures?

Tags: svn, command-line

I'm trying to update all projects in a folder (most are in same repository) to a certain revision:

```
svn update -r 1254822 -q *
```

The problem though is that one or two of the projects in the folder have a different root so do not have that revision.

Is there some way to tell it to skip those projects on failure and still update the rest?

I guess it would be safer to exclude them from the wildcard somehow.

Comment: As you've probably tested yourself, `--force` does not help. So this will need a script.

Comment: Yeah, I tried --force. Should have put that in the question really. :) Ended up just moving the relevant folders out, running the command on the rest, then moving them back.